# Android: Trying to test sockets

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I'm trying to test socket communication in Android Java, but can't seem to get a mock working.

First of all, using Mockito, `mock(Socket.class)` throws an Exception `java.lang.VerifyError`.

So I coded my mock like so:

```
public void testMyTest(){
    final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

    try{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
        os.write("poulet".getBytes());
        is.read(buffer, 0, 6);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Read result:" + (new String(buffer, "UTF-8")));
    } catch(IOException e){}
}
```

However `is` is not reading from `os` when I call `os.write()`. The raw result is `[B@42204320` and, in string form, it looks like `������������`. I tried commenting `os.write()` but nothing changed.

Does anyone know how to link an input stream to read form an output stream?

To test my classes I just called

```
final Socket mockedSocket1 = new Socket();
final Socket mockedSocket2 = new Socket();
when(mockedSocket1.getInputStream()).thenReturn(is);
when(mockedSocket2.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(os)
```

So that my classes get the linked output and input streams that I'm going to test with.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is`'s buffer will always be empty.

This: `ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());` just creates an `ByteArrayInputStream` with an empty buffer, that buffer won't change when you write something to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

> > public byte[] toByteArray()
> >
> > Creates a **newly allocated** byte array. Its size is the current size of this output stream and the valid contents of the buffer have been **copied into** it.
> >     ...

What you can do is to create the `ByteArrayInputStream` after you write something to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, eg:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
    os.write("poulet".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    try(ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());){
        is.read(buffer, 0, 6);
        System.out.println("Read result:|" + (new String(buffer, "UTF-8") + "|"));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great, however I managed to solve the problem using a `PipedInputStream` and a `PipedOutputStream`